# API - GET TASKS - custom filters

Tags: mesos

Is there a way to filter results of GET_TASKS in Mesos API ?

http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/operator-http-api/#get_tasks

There is no info about filters, like for example get TASKS that belongs to specific principal or with status done. There is no info about limit / offset. Getting whole list of tasks is slow.

Maybe there is some way to filter results ?

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to operator API but there is also general `\task` API that allow some basic filtering with query parameters:

- `framework_id=VALUE`   Only return tasks belonging to the framework with this ID.
- `limit=VALUE`          Maximum number of tasks returned (default is 100).
- `offset=VALUE`         Starts task list at offset.
- `order=(asc|desc)`     Ascending or descending sort order (default is descending).
- `task_id=VALUE`        Only return tasks with this ID (should be used together with parameter `framework_id`).

http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/endpoints/master/tasks/

Comment: Thank you, to bad, that there are no other filters available :)

Comment: AFAIK there was a graphql API design dock somewhere so maybe it's time to implement it